# Convert filetype of cert from .txt to .pem

Tags: windows, ssl, certificate

I need to add a server certificate to my trust store, and therefore a .pem file has been provided to me on github. Unfortunately, for some reason, i can't download the file, so i have copied the text and inserted the text into a .txt file. Now, i need assume that i have to convert filetype from .txt to .pem, before i can add the server certificate to my trust store in windows 10.

How do i convert a certificate in .txt to .pem? I am using windows 10

The file looks like the following:

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
xxx
xxx
...
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

Comment: How to rename a file is not a programming question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As IInspectable pointed out it is not really a programming question as you could just use the context menu of Windows explorer or hit `F2` on the selected file.

But of course this issue **can be handled programmatically** - here is the PowerShell way:

1. Open a PowerShell console window.
2. Run:

   ```
   Move-Item 'C:\my-file.txt' 'C:\my-file.pem'
   ```